# Instance of abstract class that implements Iterator won't iterate

Tags: java, foreach, interface, abstract-class, iterable

It seems like when I have an abstract class that implements an interface the interface isn't getting picked up by the main class that extends my abstract class:

When I use this:

```
public abstract class MusicIntCollection implements Iterator<Integer>{...}
```

I cannot iterate over an instance of StepIndexCollection:

```
public class StepIndexCollection extends MusicIntCollection{...}
```

However, when I create this:

```
public class StepIndexCollection extends MusicIntCollection implements Iterator<Integer>{...}
```

...I can iterate over an instance of StepIndexCollection.

Here is how I'm iterating:

```
this.notes = new StepIndexCollection();
    for (int i : o.notes()) {
        this.notes.add(i);
    }
```

Is there a way to make it work from the abstract class so all my specific class types that extend MusicIntCOllection don't also have to implement the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implementing the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface, not the [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. If you make your class implement an `Iterable`, you'll be able to use the enhanced `for` loop syntax.

Comment: If that's done in the abstract class, will it work for any subclasses?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yup. You don't have to implement the interface directly in every class.